# how to sum a column from one table and group the sum using data from column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am really having problem trying to sum up a column of one table and then group it according to the data from another table. the only common key that they have is account number.

here is the scenario

```
table 1.

account_no  volume  read_date
1            32      12016
2            22      12016
3            20      12016
4            21      12016
5            54      12016
3            65      12016
7            84      12016
8            21      12016
9            20      12016
10           30      12016
```

=========================================================

```
table 2

account_no  Zone
1            A
2            A
3            B
4            B
5            A
3            A
7            B
8            B
9            C
10           C
```

Result

```
Zone Total
A     173
B     146
C     50
```

so far this is how my query goes

```
Select sum(volume) as Total, read_date as bDate 
GROUP BY bDate 
ORDER By bDate
```

it was able to sum all the volumes based on the read_date
any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: You have me confused with the multiple account 3 records. I suppose the second #3 is really meant to be #6 in both tables? Which leads me to the question: Can there even be multiple records for a single account in table 1 or 2 or is the account number a unique key in both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, This will sum up based on read_dates and Zones

```
SELECT A.read_date
    ,B.Zone
    ,sum(A.volume) SumOfVolume
FROM @Table1 A
INNER JOIN @Table2 B ON A.account_no = B.account_no
GROUP BY A.read_date
    ,B.Zone
```

Comment: this is really such a great help... this is really right on the spot... thank you very much for your help...

Comment: @William: You are welcome. Please select the answer which works for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to `JOIN` the two tables together and do a `GROUP BY Zone`:

```
SELECT t2.Zone, SUM(volume) AS Total
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.account_no = t2.account_no
GROUP BY t2.Zone
```

Comment: Thank you Giorgos for your help... now i am having problem summing it up based on the read_dates then grouping them based on zones.

Comment: @william Can you post the required result based on `read_date`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using :

```
SELECT SUM(TBL1.Volume) AS Total, TBL2.Zone
FROM TABLE1 AS TBL1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS TBL3
ON TBL1.Account_No = TBL2.Account_No
GROUP BY TBL2.Zone
```